# What ingredients are dairy?

Tags: food, dairy

So I have this product in my hand. I'm assuming that I [can't always rely on the Kosher certification to indicate dairy status](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10957/if-a-product-with-a-hechsher-doesnt-say-dairy-does-that-mean-its-pareve/10959#10959). I look over at the ingredients panel...

What are the [ingredients I should be looking out for that would indicate dairy status](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/5082)?

In other words: If it had milk listed -- well yeah, that's obvious. But there are, I'm sure, lots of other funny-sounding (hard-to-pronounce) stuff that are listed that are truly dairy.

What are they?

Comment: -1: I disagree with the premise of this question. I think you misinterpreted the answer you're linking to. The heksherim are very reliable about telling you when products are dairy, and pretty much always usually the best way to tell whether there are any dairy ingredients in a product (much better than seeing Sodium Caseinate or Lactoglobulin on an ingredients list and knowing that it's dairy).

Comment: @Chanoch I'm not following. If I have a product in my hand, should I or should I not be looking at the ingredients? If you answer yes, I should -- I want to know (make that, need to know) what to look for.

Comment: You should look at the heksher. They're accurate. There are lots of reasons why you can't tell whether a product is dairy from the ingredients list. #1: Ingredients that you've never heard of that happen to be dairy (it would take a long time for you to build up a knowledge base to identify these accurately.) #2: when a product is made with utensils that have previously been used for dairy and not kashered. #3: I've heard that manufacturers are allowed to omit ingredients form the list if they appear in insignificant amounts (but I've never tried to find the relevant law to verify this).

Comment: @Chanoch sounds like a very good answer for my [other question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10957/128), but I'm basing this question on the answer Gershon gave.

Comment: A good place to look would probably be a resource online for people suffering from milk allergies.

Comment: @Chanoch as Menachem pointed out in his more recent answer to the same question ([here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10957/if-a-product-with-a-hechsher-doesnt-say-dairy-does-that-mean-its-pareve/11011#11011)), sometimes mistakes are made. Checking the ingredients is always a very good idea for a product you're not familiar with.

Comment: This question is also relevant for OU Dairy products when one would like to know if it is only Dairy utensils.

Comment: If the product is labelled with allergy information "This product contains SOY" or equipment information "This product is prepared in a facility that produces MILK products" then it becomes easy.

Answer (score 7):

From [Dairy Free Cooking](http://dairyfreecooking.about.com/od/dairyfreebasics/tp/Dairy-Derived-Ingredient-List.htm):
(For explanations on what they are and how they're used see the link).

- Butter
- Casein
- Cheese
- Cream
- Curd
- Delactosed
- Lactalbumin
- Lactoglobulin
- Lactose
- Milk
- Recaldent
- Whey and Whey Proteins (and anything else that begins with whey)

Also check out:  http://www.woodheadpublishing.com/en/book.aspx?bookID=1512

Comment: Products sometimes list "natural flavors" which may also be dairy.

Comment: @YDK, are you trying to say you can never be sure? If so, the question has lost all value.

Comment: @SethJ, even if YDK is correct, not *every* product lists "natural flavors".